# What is Resourcestring max size and max number limitation?

Tags: delphi

What is the maximum numbers of `resourcestrings` we have in Delphi application and what is the maximum length of `resourcestring` value we can have?

Comment: I doubt this is documented, and it is quite possibly platform dependent. You could always conduct an empirical experiment.

Comment: Yes its true, I tried to find some text on above topic, but nowhere  it is mention clearly. Even I got confuse when I saw following condition in System.LoadResString method >>>  if ResStringRec.Identifier < 64*1024 then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the Windows platform it is documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381050(v=vs.85).aspx)

> STRINGTABLE resource
>   stringID Unsigned 16-bit integer that identifies the resource.
>   string One or more strings, enclosed in quotation marks. The string must be no longer than 4097 characters

Further, there's an error in Delphi:

> E2381 Resource string length exceeds Windows limit of 4096 characters